# JTidy upgrade broke document xpaths

Tags: java, xpath, jtidy

I just updated to the newest version of jtidy which came out in october and it seems to have broken my document object for unknown reasons. This is my code:

```
tidy = new Tidy();
tidy.setShowWarnings(false);
tidy.setShowErrors(0);
tidy.setQuiet(true);
tidy.setMakeClean(true);

URL url = new URL(url_string);
Document doc = tidy.parseDOM(url.openStream(), null);

String xpath_string = "//table[@id='links']//a";
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpath_string);
NodeList n = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: -1
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.eval(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.eval(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at IndoorClimbing.main(IndoorClimbing.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.ExpandedNameTable.getType(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBase.indexNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.dom2dtm.DOM2DTM.addNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.dom2dtm.DOM2DTM.nextNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBase._firstch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBase.getFirstChild(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBaseTraversers$ChildTraverser.first(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.AxesWalker.getNextNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.AxesWalker.nextNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.WalkingIterator.nextNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.NodeSequence.nextNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.NodeSequence.runTo(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.NodeSequence.setRoot(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.LocPathIterator.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
---------
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.ExpandedNameTable.getType(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBase.indexNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.dom2dtm.DOM2DTM.addNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.dom2dtm.DOM2DTM.nextNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBase._firstch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBase.getFirstChild(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBaseTraversers$ChildTraverser.first(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.AxesWalker.getNextNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.AxesWalker.nextNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.WalkingIterator.nextNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.NodeSequence.nextNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.NodeSequence.runTo(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.NodeSequence.setRoot(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.LocPathIterator.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.eval(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.eval(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at IndoorClimbing.main(IndoorClimbing.java:55)
--------------- linked to ------------------
javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at IndoorClimbing.main(IndoorClimbing.java:55)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: -1
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.eval(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl.eval(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.ExpandedNameTable.getType(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBase.indexNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.dom2dtm.DOM2DTM.addNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.dom2dtm.DOM2DTM.nextNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBase._firstch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBase.getFirstChild(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBaseTraversers$ChildTraverser.first(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.AxesWalker.getNextNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.AxesWalker.nextNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.WalkingIterator.nextNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.NodeSequence.nextNode(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.NodeSequence.runTo(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.NodeSequence.setRoot(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.LocPathIterator.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

The error occurs at the last line of code when trying to generate the NodeList. Has anyone had issues like this with the new version of JTidy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had a similar problem. Found a rather silly workaround (to re-parse the jtidy output) that suggests a problem with jTidy.

```
document = tidy.parseDOM(rstream, null); 

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Source xmlSource = new DOMSource(document);
Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(outputStream);
TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(xmlSource, outputTarget);
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());

Document doc = db.parse(is);
```

It took me hours; hope this helpes.

Comment: DANG.  This just bit me too.  Thanks for the hard work myFriendJoe!

Answer (score 0):

Since the error happens in `com.sun.org.apache`, I don't think it's an JTidy issue.

Try to strip down your example so you can file a bug report against the [XalanJ project](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/).