# I am getting (XPath Assertion : TransformerException: -1 for: //COMMAND/TXNSTATUS/text()='1004031') in Assertion Results in jmeter 5.5

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

(XPath Assertion : TransformerException: -1 for: //COMMAND/TXNSTATUS/text()='1004031') in Assertion Results in jmeter 5.5. I am using Xpath Assertion along with Assertion Results listner.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue with [jTidy](https://github.com/jtidy/jtidy). If your response is valid XML/XHTML you can try unticking `Use Tidy` box.

[image]

If it's not valid and you have to use Tidy you can try [parsing it twice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1856319/2897748) using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) or switch to i.e. [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)